# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} \int\limits_{1}^{x} \sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}\,\mathrm dt$

Tags: integration, limits

Can anyone help me by calculating this limit?

I know that I need L'Hôpital but how?

$$
\lim_{x \to 1^+}\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} \int_{1}^{x} \sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)} \,\mathrm dt
$$

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please use different symbols for the upper bound of the integral and for the integrand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since my hints were not helpful, here a is my solution
$$
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to 1^+}\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\int\limits_{1}^{x}\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}dt
&=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\left(\int\limits_{1}^{x}\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}dt\right)'}{((x-1)^2)'}&\text{L'Hopitale rule}\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi x)}}{2(x-1)}& y\to x-1\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi (y+1))}}{2y}&\cos(\pi+\alpha)=-\cos\alpha\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(\pi y)}}{2y}&1-\cos\alpha=2\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{2}|\sin\frac{\pi y}{2}|}{2y}&y>0\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin\frac{\pi y}{2}}{2y}&\sin\alpha\sim\alpha\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{2}\frac{\pi y}{2}}{2y}\\
&=\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $$ \lim_{x,1+}\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} \int_{1}^{x} \sqrt{1+cos(\pi t)} dt $$ 
i used L'Hospital so i got this: 
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+cos(\pi *x)}} {2*(x-1)}$$
so i used l'Hospital again:
and again...and again
so i got this:
$$\frac{\pi * (2*cos(\pi*x))+(3*cos(2*\pi *x)+2))*\sqrt{1+cos(\pi*x)}} {2*sin(\pi*x)*(3*cos(\pi*x)+2)}$$
now i dont know how to continue.

Comment: You need to aplly that rule only once, then substitute $y=x-1$, then $y\to 0$

Comment: @Xorkox Is it clear now?

Comment: no :/
substitude this doesnt help me :(
i am confused

Comment: @Xorkox see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Integrate the equivalent, valid when $t\gt1$, $t\to1$,
$$
\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}=\sqrt2\,\sin\left(\frac\pi2(t-1)\right)\sim\frac\pi{\sqrt2}\,(t-1).
$$
This yields, for $x\to1$, $x\gt1$,
$$
\int_1^x\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}\mathrm dt\sim\frac\pi{\sqrt2}\int_1^x(t-1)\mathrm dt=\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}(x-1)^2.
$$